# What is the difference between Transfer and TransferChecked instruction from the SPL Token Program?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, transfer, transfer-checked, spl-token-program

I'm curious what the practical difference is between the `Transfer` and `TransferChecked` instructions, and when should we use one over the other.

In this question, I'm using `Transfer`/`TransferChecked` as an example, but there are other instructions that are suffixed with `Checked` and it would be great if there would be a generic answer.

I found a [reference](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/token-2022-v0.4.1/token/program/src/instruction.rs#L250-L252) in the `solana-program-library` repo that explains it as follows:

> This instruction differs from Transfer in that the token mint and decimals value is checked by the caller. This may be useful when creating transactions offline or within a hardware wallet.

This explains how the two are different in usage, but it does not explain why one should be used over the other.

> the token mint and decimals value is checked by the caller

In what sense are the token mint and decimals 'checked' by the caller? What is the benefit of this approach and who 'checked' it before?

Is there a recommended one to use? Do we miss out on something if we use one over the other?

Some input here would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please update to clarify that you are inquiring about instructions from the SPL Token program

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I looked into this a bit myself a while ago, definitely not an expert but this is what I figured out: I think it's basically that the `_checked` variant requires you to pass the mint account and the number of decimals the token has, and if you pass the wrong mint account or decimals number then it will error. If it errors then the transaction is rolled back safely. This is presumably intended so that you don't accidentally eg. send someone 1,000,000 tokens when you meant to send them 10 because you thought it had 6 decimals but it actually has 1. Or send the wrong token.

The amount you send is always `10^decimals`. So if you have the number of decimals wrong you can send a very different number to what you intended.

The distinction actually carries all the way through to the core Rust code that processes the instruction, so they're separate instructions in the program code. The relevant source code is this file: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/processor.rs

Here's what it does when it processes a `Transfer` instruction:

```
TokenInstruction::Transfer { amount } => {
  msg!("Instruction: Transfer");
  Self::process_transfer(program_id, accounts, amount, None)
}
```

And when it processes a `TransferChecked` one:

```
TokenInstruction::TransferChecked { amount, decimals } => {
  msg!("Instruction: TransferChecked");
  Self::process_transfer(program_id, accounts, amount, Some(decimals))
}
```

So they're both calling `process_transfer`, the checked one passes in a `Some(decimals)` as the last argument while the unchecked passes `None`.

Here's `process_transfer`:

```
pub fn process_transfer(
  program_id: &Pubkey,
  accounts: &[AccountInfo],
  amount: u64,
  expected_decimals: Option<u8>,
) -> ProgramResult
```

That last argument is `expected_decimals`, an option. So that matches.

Here's some of what that function does:

```
let expected_mint_info = if let Some(expected_decimals) = expected_decimals {
  Some((next_account_info(account_info_iter)?, expected_decimals))
} else {
  None
};
```

If `expected_decimals` is defined (as in the checked case, but not the unchecked one), it reads the mint account from the `accounts` list and the expected decimals number. If not then `expected_mint_info` is None. No mint account or expected decimals is recorded.

Later on:

```
if let Some((mint_info, expected_decimals)) = expected_mint_info {
  if !Self::cmp_pubkeys(mint_info.key, &source_account.mint) {
    return Err(TokenError::MintMismatch.into());
  }

  let mint = Mint::unpack(&mint_info.data.borrow_mut())?;
  if expected_decimals != mint.decimals {
    return Err(TokenError::MintDecimalsMismatch.into());
  }
}
```

This is where it's doing the checks the documentation referred to. It only does these if `expected_mint_info` is defined, which only happens for the checked call. Here it's checking that the passed `mint` account has the expected address, and that its number of decimals is the one we passed in. If they don't match the transaction errors.

If you check the source code you'll see it basically works the same for all these checked/unchecked variants. They all have an optional `expected_decimals` that triggers them to read a mint account and perform the same checks.

In terms of why you'd use one over the other, the only thing I can think of is that using the unchecked is a performance optimisation. It requires you to fetch and pass less data from the client, and it requires the instruction to do less work.

Also FWIW it looks like `Transfer` has been deprecated in `program-2022`, which is the upcoming new version of the token program: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program-2022/src/processor.rs#L1212

```
#[allow(deprecated)]
TokenInstruction::Transfer { amount } => {
  msg!("Instruction: Transfer");
  Self::process_transfer(program_id, accounts, amount, None, None)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

@callum-m nailed it. There's an added benefit that's less obvious in that hardware wallets can display the transfer amount and asset safely and correctly with `TransferChecked` whereas they cannot with `Transfer`.  The processor for `Transfer` simply checks that source and destination mints match implicitly by comparing the mint assignments from the accounts' data. However it isn't possible to upload account data to a hardware wallet in a trusted way, so instead the new instruction(s) were introduced such that by signing the transaction, the owner is explicitly asserting the intended mint and decimals.  This was actually the main motivation for introducing the `*Checked` variants throughout SPL Token.